# Trying to do dual boot install: The test of the file system with type ext4 in partition #1 of SCSI2 (0, 0, 0) found uncorrected errors

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

My Ubuntu computer crashed recently, and I did recover the important things and put them on a USB drive, but I'd still rather not wipe everything off my computer, so I thought I'd do a dual installation and have Ubuntu running alongside the crashed Ubuntu. When I put in the live cd and tried doing a dual boot install I got this error

> The test of the file system with type ext4 in partition #1 of SCSI2
>   (0, 0, 0) found uncorrected errors
>
> If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct these
>   errors, the partition will be used as is

My options are go back and continue, so I press continue and get this error.

> An error occurred while writing the changes to the storage devices.
>
> The resize operation has been aborted.

I also noticed a screen covered in orange and writing once not long after I had inserted the live cd and before I tried doing dual boot installation. I took a picture of it but  I'm having trouble uploading it. These are some of the things it said

> status: { DRDY ERR }da, sector 151452203931051
>
> Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 1891273

I think I'll try uploading the picture on another computer because it says a lot of stuff and I can't type it all... Is my hard drive ruined?

Comment: Looks like a broken HDD that's about to die. Launch the Disks Utility from the Live CD, and see what it has to say.

Comment: Don't think xfce has it install, anyway, the command is `gnome-disk-utility`.

Comment: Ok yeah, the smart status is "disk has a few bad sectors". For airflow temperature it says "failing". There are also warnings on reallocated sector count and current pending sector count.

Comment: Do you think reformatting the HDD will fix it?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, it will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your disk is dying. Replace it *immediately* -- buy locally (don't wait to have something shipped by mail order). Also, the temperature warning suggests your case may have inadequate ventilation, so you may want to look into adding a fan or installing the new drive in another slot (assuming this is a desktop and not a laptop). If you need more advice on this issue, you should post photos of the interior of your case, showing where your disk bays are and any existing fans.